# Terraform how to access resource local name as a variable inside the resource block itself

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_subnet" "goodsubnet" {
  vpc_id     = "VPCID"
  cidr_block = "x.x.x.x/x"
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  tags = 
    {
      tagname1 = "$something"
    }
  
}
```

I want the tag "tagname1" to dynamically have the value of the resource local name i.e "**goodsubnet**" Is there a variable I can use?

Thanks

Comment: That is not possible. You can use a variable though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible the way you want to do it. However, Terraform has a concept of variables, which you can use to assign values to arguments. That could be either a local value [1] or an input variable [2]. For example, an input variable definition:

```
variable "subnet_name_tag" {
  type        = string
  description = "Tag name for a subnet."
}
```

Then, in your code you would do:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "goodsubnet" {
  vpc_id     = "VPCID"
  cidr_block = "x.x.x.x/x"
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  tags = 
    {
      tagname1 = var.subnet_name_tag
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a local value:

```
locals {
  subnet_tag_name = "goodsubnet"
}
```

Followed by:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "goodsubnet" {
  vpc_id     = "VPCID"
  cidr_block = "x.x.x.x/x"
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  tags = 
    {
      tagname1 = local.subnet_name_tag
    }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables

Comment: Thanks Marko. I assume I won't be able to do this either

resource "aws_subnet" local.subnet_name_tag {
  vpc_id     = "VPCID"
  cidr_block = "x.x.x.x/x"
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  tags = 
    {
      tagname1 = local.subnet_name_tag
    }
}

Comment: No, that is not possible as well.